# Is there anyway to get the nearest element to the cursor?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a bunch of `<p>` tags, I want to get the value of the `<p>` tag nearest to the current cursor position, how can I do so? I have searched alot about this topic but coudln't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get the current cursor position

```
document.onmousemove = e => {
    cursorX = e.clientX;
    cursorY = e.clientY;
};
```

`cursorX` and `cursorY` are global variables already declared in your program

Now you need to get the nearest element to those coordinates

```
document.elementFromPoint(cursorX, cursorY)
```

Hope this helps